# Why PDF without cmap can render characters?

Tags: pdf

**EDITED at 17:54 26.02.2020**

PDFs in the following link look sane but give garbled text when copying because they lack cmap. I don't understand why rendering is performed properly and want to know which information is used to determine characters to render.

https://github.com/angea/PDF101/tree/master/handcoded/textextract

Please note that I'm asking for mechanism but not for solution.

Comment: I think sometimes people generate PDF files with garbage unicode maps on purpose, to prevent text extraction. Posting the PDF here for review is the best thing to do. Though either way, you might need to do OCR to "repair" the PDF.

Comment: Sorry I'm not asking for solution but for mechanism. I added link to PDFs on my initial post.

Answer (score 1):

There are two fonts on page 1, and both are missing any encoding information in the PDF metadata. In particular there is no ToUnicode map.

Therefore PDF readers have to rely on the font itself, and possibly the character codes used in the content stream.

In the screenshot below, the left side is the font data in the PDF, and on the right is the content stream of the first page. As you can see, the first character code is 0x2e, which maps to the glyph "T" but in Unicode U+002e is "period". The next character code is 0x08, which is a control character. This is why, if you select text from the PDF, the first character would be "." and the second would be garbage.

[image]

> Why PDF without cmap can render characters?

Because the fonts internal CMap maps the character codes in the PDF page content stream to the correct glyph in the font, so you see glyphs that make sense. However, both the PDF and the font itself, are missing any sensible Unicode mappings, hence you get garbage when you copy+paste the text.

Answer (score 1):

ACCORDING TO https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/526157/what-is-identity-h-encoding-should-it-be-avoided-and-if-so-how
CMAP is a mapping between CID and GID. It can render when CMAP and file is available.
TOUNICODE CMAP is a mapping between CID and GID. It makes you can extract information from PDF.